# Edit form not being instantiated

Tags: django, forms

I have two models like this:

```
class OptionsAndFeatures(models.Model):
   options = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   entertainment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   seats_trim = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   convenience = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   body_exterior = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   lighting = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   safety = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   powertrain = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   suspension_handling = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   specs_dimensions = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   offroad_capability = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
class Vehicle(models.Model):
   ...
   options_and_features = models.ForeignKey(OptionsAndFeatures, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a model form for the `OptionsAndFeatures`class that I'm using in both the add and edit views.  In the add view it works just fine.  But the edit view renders the `OptionsAndFeatures` as blank.  The code for the edit view is as follows:

```
def edit_vehicle(request, stock_number=None):   
   vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle, stock_number=stock_number)

   if request.method == 'POST':
      # save info
   else:
       vehicle_form = VehicleForm(instance=vehicle)
       photos = PhotosFormSet(instance=vehicle)
       options = OptionsForm(instance=vehicle)

   #render_to_reponse
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `Vehicle` object in as the `instance` argument to a form presumably based on the `OptionsAndFeatures` class. This won't work - obviously you'll need an OptionsAndFeatures object.